# How to find isothermal coordinates equivalent to circles in far limit?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, curves-and-surfaces

I am trying to find the most general rotational coordinate systems for Euclidean 3-space, with the following two defining characteristics: 1) being equivalent to spherical coordinates in the limit of large distances from the origin, and 2) for the $\phi$=constant plane ($\phi$ is the azimuthal coordinate with $0\leq \phi \lt 2\pi$), the remaining coordinates $(u,v)$ are isothermal.  So in this plane the standard cylindrical coordinates are $(\rho,z)$, $z$ being the axis of rotation, and $\rho$ being the normal distance from that axis.  Define the following complex variable $\psi$.$$\psi=z+i\rho=re^{i\theta}=r(cos\theta+isin\theta)$$with $0\leq \theta\leq\pi$ and $(r,\theta)$ being the standard spherical coordinates.  In that far limit, for the $\phi$ = constant plane, one of the coordinates is a family of circles with origin as center, and the other coordinate's asymptotes are a family of straight lines through the origin.  It seems that the easiest way to study this is with conformal transformations $\psi=F(w)$ where $w=u+iv$.  Then $\rho$ and $z$ both satisfy the 2-D Laplacian (and so do $u$ and $v$ ).  In texts I can only find four functions which work (all have symmetry about the $z=0$ plane): $F(w)=$\begin{cases}e^w\\\cosh(w)\\\sinh(w)\\\sqrt(e^w+1)\\\end{cases}which in the case of rotational coordinate systems correspond respectively to the following : spherical, oblate and prolate spheroidal, and Cassinian ovoidal. The first 3 functions are derivable as the first term of the solution of the Laplacian by separation of variables (easy), and the last one seems to be a special solution of the Laplacian. Is it significant that these systems all involve only the exponential function (cosh and sinh are sums of them)?  I would think that there are an infinite number of such systems, but how does one find them?  By studying the solutions to the 2-D Laplacian, as infinite series or integrals?, or by conformal analysis?, or homotopy?  These things can get very messy very quickly, so something with insight is probably needed.  As a physicist, this seems to me like a very useful question, but way beyond my abilities. Any graduate students out there who need a good thesis question?  Or is there an easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Let me give what I think is an infinite set of such systems, and you can tell me whether it's what you had in mind:  $e^w + p(e^w)e^{-(k+1)w}$, where $p(w)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$.

The first three examples you listed correspond, up to constants, to $p(w) = 0$, $p(w) = 1$, and $p(w) = -1$, respectively.

For $u=Re(w)$ large, $|e^w|$ is large, so $|p(e^w)e^{-(k+1)w}|\leq C|e^{-w}|$ is small.  Therefore $e^w + p(e^w)e^{-(k+1)w}$ is quite close to the spherical-coordinates transformation $e^w$, so the asymptotic behaviour is circles-and-lines.

Comment: That's a very nice and relatively simple function that does seem to work in all but the Cassini case, which is perhaps exceptional for some unknown reason.  And it is an infinite set.  The logical question to ask is, are there other infinite sets? Or sets that include the Cassini case? Perhaps there exists some reasonable condition that would eliminate cases like Cassini. Let me cogitate on this awhile before I except it as the answer, but your answer at least gives me a very decent working start. Thanks!

Comment: After looking at the reasonable solution by macbeth, I  don't think it generates an infinite series of useful isothermal coordinate systems, because they are not necessarily symmetric about the z = 0 plane, except in the first 3 cases above.  Those cases are the first terms of infinite series generated by separation of variables of the 2-D Laplacian, but the Cassinian ovals are a special solution not generated by this method. So I guess the question could be restated: How does one find special solutions to the 2-D Laplacian that have the desired properties far from the origin?  Not easy.

Comment: This is interesting, Bob, but can you explain more? I'm not quite sure what you mean by "symmetric about the z = 0 plane"  -- do you mean the same as "transformation of the complex plane symmetric about the y-axis"?

Comment: I have edited the question so that it is now more clear.  Originally the variable z was used in two very different ways (as in Moon & Spencer), one as a complex variable, and the other as one of the cylindrical coordinates (real).  I still need to look more closely at your series, which may very well be valuable.

Comment: After studying this for a few weeks, I don't think there are any other practical coordinate systems with the desired characteristics besides spherical, and oblate and prolate spheroidal.